# Why does this form keep submitting stale params?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a `comment` form that is rendered multiple times on my page, because each `comment` is associated with a `node` and each `node` is rendered multiple times.

However, whenever a comment is successfully sent (via remote), when I try to send another one it keeps sending the first params.

See logs here:

```
Started POST "/nodes/101/comments" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-07-08 16:48:46 -0500
Processing by CommentsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "comment"=>{"message"=>"Comment 1"}, "node_id"=>"101"}
  User Load (2.9ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 57  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  FamilyTree Load (2.7ms)  SELECT  "family_trees".* FROM "family_trees"  WHERE "family_trees"."user_id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 57]]
  Role Load (1.7ms)  SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "users_roles" ON "roles"."id" = "users_roles"."role_id" WHERE "users_roles"."user_id" = $1 AND (((roles.name = 'admin') AND (roles.resource_type IS NULL) AND (roles.resource_id IS NULL)))  [["user_id", 57]]
  Node Load (4.1ms)  SELECT  "nodes".* FROM "nodes"  WHERE "nodes"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 101]]
   (1.8ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (1.8ms)  INSERT INTO "comments" ("created_at", "message", "node_id", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", "2015-07-08 21:48:47.078077"], ["message", "Comment 1"], ["node_id", 101], ["updated_at", "2015-07-08 21:48:47.078077"], ["user_id", 57]]
   (2.5ms)  COMMIT
   (1.7ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (1.7ms)  UPDATE "nodes" SET "cached_comment_count" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "nodes"."id" = 101  [["cached_comment_count", 3], ["updated_at", "2015-07-08 21:48:47.088576"]]
   (2.1ms)  COMMIT
  Rendered comments/create.html.erb (0.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 97ms (Views: 7.4ms | ActiveRecord: 31.0ms)


Started POST "/nodes/101/comments" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-07-08 16:48:51 -0500
Processing by CommentsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "comment"=>{"message"=>"Comment 1"}, "node_id"=>"101"}
  User Load (2.9ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 57  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  FamilyTree Load (2.2ms)  SELECT  "family_trees".* FROM "family_trees"  WHERE "family_trees"."user_id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 57]]
  Role Load (12.7ms)  SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "users_roles" ON "roles"."id" = "users_roles"."role_id" WHERE "users_roles"."user_id" = $1 AND (((roles.name = 'admin') AND (roles.resource_type IS NULL) AND (roles.resource_id IS NULL)))  [["user_id", 57]]
  Node Load (2.0ms)  SELECT  "nodes".* FROM "nodes"  WHERE "nodes"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 101]]
   (3.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (4.3ms)  INSERT INTO "comments" ("created_at", "message", "node_id", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", "2015-07-08 21:48:51.243386"], ["message", "Comment 1"], ["node_id", 101], ["updated_at", "2015-07-08 21:48:51.243386"], ["user_id", 57]]
   (6.2ms)  COMMIT
   (2.3ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (26.9ms)  UPDATE "nodes" SET "cached_comment_count" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "nodes"."id" = 101  [["cached_comment_count", 4], ["updated_at", "2015-07-08 21:48:51.264565"]]
   (13.4ms)  COMMIT
  Rendered comments/create.html.erb (1.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 131ms (Views: 9.2ms | ActiveRecord: 76.0ms)
```

Here is the view that this is rendered on - `views/dashboard/index.html.erb`

```
      <% @nodes.each do |node| %>
        <% @card_number += 1 %>

<div class="card-input">
  Node Id: <%= node.id %>
  <%= simple_form_for([node, Comment.new], remote: true) do |f| %>
   <%= f.error_notification %>
      <%= f.input_field :message, as: :text, id: "card-input-field-#{@card_number}", class: "input-field", placeholder: "Share your thoughts", cols: "30", rows: "10" %>
      <%= content_tag(:a, '', :name => 'submit', :class => 'input-submit icon-circle-right') %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Note that on first load, it renders everything each `Node ID` correctly.

This is the `comments_controller#create`:

```
  def create
    @node = Node.find(params[:node_id])
    @comment = current_user.comments.new(comment_params)
    @comment.node = @node
    @node.cached_comment_count += 1

    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.save and @node.save

        # format.html { redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Comment was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @comment, status: :created }
        format.js
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.js
      end
    end
  end
```

How do I get every operation after the first to contain the correct params and not the first one?

**Edit 1**

It seems the issue lies in the `content_tag` for the submit. Here is the JS that governs that:

```
  $(".input-submit").click(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $("#new_comment").submit();
  });
```

Once I change the submit on the `simple_form_for` to:

```
 f.button :submit
```

**Edit 2**

I have changed the form declaration to include an `id`, that I can reference, specifically:

```
<%= simple_form_for([node, Comment.new], html: { id: "new_comment_card-#{@card_number}"}, remote: true) do |f| %>
```

But, in my JS (i.e. the snippet in Edit 1 above), how do I submit the form that I have clicked in and am typing in? I tried messing around with `this` but it didn't work out like I expected.

My first step was trying to just even get an output of what `this` is when I click the button and I got nothing printed to my console. I did this:

```
  $(".input-submit").click(function(event) {
      console.log(this);
      event.preventDefault();
      $("#new_comment").submit();
  });
```

...Yet my console still came up blank.

Comment: `$("#new_comment").submit()` – that will always submit the one specific form that has the id `new_comment`. (You are aware that an id has to be unique within a document, right?)

Comment: @CBroe - Yes I am aware that it has to be unique within a document. Given that I have multiple forms on my page, how do I submit the right one within the context above?

Comment: Use [`.parents()`](https://api.jquery.com/parents/) to find the form element ancestor of the clicked submit link.

Comment: @CBroe I would rather just select the right ID for the form I am submitting. I added a dynamic element to my form as you can see above (I edited the question), but I am not sure how to grab that unique ID in the JS. Any ideas?

Comment: Why, what benefit do you think that would have? Fact is, since the click happens on the link, you need to find the corresponding form _somehow_ – and using `.parent` or `.parents` is a perfectly fine way of doing that. (And once you’ve done that, you can still grab the value of the id attribute of that form, if you still think that would be necessary.) You _could_ of course store the form id on the link element itself in the HTML already (f.e. using a custom data attribute), and then grab it “directly” from the clicked link. But that doesn’t have any real advantage here IMHO.

Comment: @CBroe Can you leave an answer with more code than just `.parents()` to illustrate how I might use it to solve my issue please? Thanks.

Comment: Why are you submitting using an <a> tag? If you used an <button type='submit'> then the form submission would work *without* Javascript

Comment: @Gareth I was initially doing it for styling, but I did change it to a `input type='submit'...` and it still didn't work. The main issue was that the form was submitting the wrong params, i.e. the params not associated with the current form, but rather the last rendered form. In other words, if I have 3 forms on my page and I fill out the first, but press `submit`, the form submitted is the empty form that is third (aka last rendered). So the answer by CBroe seems to have solved that problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the form your link is a descendant of, you can simply use jQuery’s <del>`parent` method (or `parents`, if the link is not a direct child of the form),</del> `closest` method, like so:

```
$('.input-submit').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).closest('form').submit();
});
```

That will simply submit the form the link is “in”, without any need to select the form by a more specific method such as finding it via its id or anything.

Comment: In this case `parents` will work, because it's unlikely that a form will be nested in another form, but a better method to use is [`closest`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)

Comment: @Gareth: You’re right, `closest` is more appropriate here, I edited the answer. (I keep forgetting that `parents` doesn’t “stop” once it finds an element that matches the selector, but keeps on going …)

Comment: This works perfectly. Both answers worked actually, but this one is more 'fail proof' I guess.

Comment: I have another question that is related to this, I will ask a fresh one and put link here if you are interested. I suspect you should be able to tackle that one too.

Comment: Here is the other question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31355648/how-do-i-preserve-the-this-from-a-previous-js-state-and-transfer-it-to-another