# How do I preserve the `this` from a previous JS state and transfer it to another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

So I have a view that has a simple_form, which looks like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for([node, Comment.new], html: { id: "new_comment_card-#{@card_number}"}, remote: true) do |f| %>
        <%= f.error_notification %>
        <%= f.input_field :message, as: :text, id: "card-input-field-#{@card_number}", class: "input-field", placeholder: "Share your thoughts", cols: "30", rows: "10" %>
        <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

This form appears multiple times on the same view, hence the dynamic `id` specified.

When that button is pressed, some JS intercepts the submit like so (to ensure the submit sends the right credentials for the right form):

```
  $(".input-submit").click(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $(this).closest('form').submit();
  });
```

Otherwise sometimes the last rendered form would get submitted and that leads to all manner of issues.

When that is submitted, eventually it leads to `CommentsController#Create` which looks like this:

```
  def create
    @node = Node.find(params[:node_id])
    @comment = current_user.comments.new(comment_params)
    @comment.node = @node

    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.save and @node.save
        format.html
        format.js
      else
        format.html
        format.js
      end
    end
  end
```

That then looks for and executes - `create.js.erb`. I want my `create.js.erb` to do 3 things:

1. Add the newly saved comment to the top of the current `div#id=card-comments`, perhaps with a little animation to show the new comment.
2. Push the other list of existing comments down to make way for the newly created comment from Step 1.
3. Remove the text from the input field, so the user can add another comment without refreshing, perhaps with a little jiggle/highlight/animation.

I am not sure how to achieve this - JS is not my strong suit.

I tried doing this in my `create.js.erb`, but I have all sorts of weird behavior including duplicating the entire content of the comments on 1 card to the comments on another card:

```
$('#card-comments').append("<%= j (render partial: 'nodes/comment', collection: @node.comments) %>");
```

How do I achieve the above?

Comment: Are you sure about "last rendered form would get submitted"? Sounds unlikely to me (if the forms are not nested and have unique ids)

Comment: Now that I think about it, I'd bet on duplicated ids.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Yes, I believe it is duplicated ids is the issue - I just don't know how to fix it. I have divs with unique IDs that the comments live within.  Each comment block lives within the class `.card-comments`, but that is a child of a div that has a unique ID `<div class="card" id="card-<%= @card_number %>">`. So, I could target that div, but the question is...how do I know which ID to target? i.e. there are 10 cards rendered on the page at any one time, how do I pass the fact that the comment was just added on `card-3` to the `create.js.erb`. That's what I am struggling with.

Comment: Simple, just add `card_id=3` to form parameters (as a hidden field, for example). This way you'll know the id to use in your `.js.erb` file.

Answer (score 0):

If the user can submit comments on multiple cards on the page, it should submit a parameter to the controller indicating which card the comment was submitted on and the JS should replace the comments **of that specific card**.  Currently your jQuery selector is on #card-comments which doesn't match a specific card.  Perhaps place the comments in a div with a specific ID similar to the form and **replace all the comments** of that div:

```
$('#card-<%= params[:node_id] %>-comments').html("<%= j (render partial: 'nodes/comment', collection: @node.comments) %>");
```

Comment: That's exactly what I am trying to do, but I am not sure how to do that from within the `create.js.erb`. Each card has a unique ID, i.e. `card-1, card-2, etc.`. The question is, how do I take that most recently created comment, and add it to the current card from within the `create.js.erb`. Do you have a code sample you could show me?